# Project not getting deployed on JBOSS its giving error MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS

Tags: java, jboss, spring-tool-suite

am trying to deploy my project on JBOSS 6.0, when i try to start my JBOSS its giving me the following error

> MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS: JBAS018680: Failed
>   to start HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory

I checked the java version, standalone.xml they are looking fine am not able figure out why the server is throwing this error

please find the full stack trace below

```
     09:43:05,512 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA-redhat-1
        09:43:05,730 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA-redhat-2
        09:43:05,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA (AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4) starting
        09:43:06,839 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] JBAS015002: Deployment of 'BMS.ear' requested, but the deployment is not present
        09:43:06,855 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
        09:43:06,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
        09:43:06,855 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
        09:43:06,870 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.14.GA-redhat-1
        09:43:06,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
        09:43:06,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
        09:43:06,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
        09:43:06,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.14.Final-redhat-2
        09:43:06,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
        09:43:06,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
        09:43:06,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
        09:43:07,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
        09:43:07,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
        09:43:07,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.13.Final-redhat-1)
        09:43:07,292 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
        09:43:07,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.1)
        09:43:07,495 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.6.GA-redhat-2
        09:43:07,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
        09:43:07,542 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
        09:43:07,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
        09:43:07,760 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8181
        09:43:07,854 WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-7) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
        09:43:07,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
        09:43:07,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasource/BMSDataSource]
        09:43:07,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
        09:43:07,994 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=C:\jboss server\jboss-eap-6.0_V1\standalone\data\messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=C:\jboss server\jboss-eap-6.0_V1\standalone\data\messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\jboss server\jboss-eap-6.0_V1\standalone\data\messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\jboss server\jboss-eap-6.0_V1\standalone\data\messagingpaging)
        09:43:07,994 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Waiting to obtain live lock
        09:43:08,025 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Using NIO Journal
        09:43:08,041 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
        09:43:08,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/BMSInvoiceDataSource]
        09:43:08,120 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Waiting to obtain live lock
        09:43:08,120 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Live Server Obtained live lock
        09:43:08,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss server\jboss-eap-6.0_V1\standalone\deployments
        09:43:08,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9997
        09:43:08,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4448
        09:43:08,619 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Started Netty Acceptor version
3.2.6.Final-redhat-2-20df069 127.0.0.1:5445 for CORE protocol
        09:43:08,619 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Started Netty Acceptor version
3.2.6.Final-redhat-2-20df069 127.0.0.1:5455 for CORE protocol
        09:43:08,635 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Server is now live
        09:43:08,635 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) HornetQ Server version 2.2.19.SNAPSHOT (HQ_2_2_23_Final, 122) [e1f1f1d7-d2fc-11e6-ac8d-2978dc5edd5e]) started
        09:43:08,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
        09:43:08,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
        09:43:08,760 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
        09:43:08,838 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-4) HornetQ resource adaptor started
        09:43:08,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
        09:43:08,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
        09:43:09,306 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS: JBAS018680: Failed to start HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory
            at org.jboss.as.cmp.keygenerator.hilo.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.start(HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.java:72)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.initialize(OracleSql.java:110)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1697)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1674)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:275)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:375)
            at org.jboss.as.cmp.keygenerator.hilo.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.createTableIfNotExists(HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.java:147)
            at org.jboss.as.cmp.keygenerator.hilo.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.initSequence(HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.java:96)
            at org.jboss.as.cmp.keygenerator.hilo.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.start(HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.java:70)
            ... 5 more

        09:43:09,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
        JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.cmp.keygen.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory.DB_KEYS: JBAS018680: Failed to start HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory

        09:43:09,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9998/management
        09:43:09,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9998
        09:43:09,338 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.0.1.GA (AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4) started (with errors) in 4185ms - Started 174 of 264 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 85 services are passive or on-demand)
        09:43:17,918 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]

        09:45:27,990 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]

        09:47:37,991 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]

        09:49:48,060 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]

        09:51:58,130 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]

        09:54:08,161 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:703)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:506) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:474) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:378) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
```

Comment: Does anyone know the root cause ??? it's kind of urgent actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem,

From reference https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

I have added the my EJB-jar's modules in application.xml

```
    <module> 
        <java>MY-JAR.jar</java> 
    </module>
```

and also set ear-subdeployments isolated to false so that EAR can read them

```
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
```